# Uploading a video to Youtube stops in the middle. (Not crash) - Android10

Tags: android, video, youtube, upload, youtube-api

I am trying to upload a video to Youtube using data api on Android. But it stops in the middle. It does not mean crash. If the video capacity is 100, it will upload well up to 20. However, it does not proceed after 20. Sometimes it doesn't go from 0.

Here is my code. The try catch is omitted.

```
Context context = context_object;
String youtubeAccountName = youtube_account_name;
Uri videoUri = video_uri;

ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
scopes.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY);
scopes.add(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);

GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, scopes);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(youtubeAccountName);

final Video video = new Video();

VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
status.setPrivacyStatus("unlisted");
video.setStatus(status);

VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
snippet.setTitle(title);
snippet.setDescription(description);
snippet.setCategoryId("19"); 
video.setSnippet(snippet);

InputStreamContent mediaContent = null;
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(videoUri, "r");
FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
Cursor c = cr.query(videoUri, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int sizeColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.SIZE);
long length = c.getLong(sizeColumnIndex);
mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("video/*", new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
mediaContent.setLength(length);
c.close();

final YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            credential.initialize(httpRequest);
            httpRequest.setIOExceptionHandler(new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(new     
                ExponentialBackOff()));
        }
}).setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).build();
final YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert =    
    youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status",video, mediaContent);

MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
int chunkSize = MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE * 6; //1572864
uploader.setChunkSize(chunkSize);
final FileInputStream finalFileInputStream = fileInputStream;
MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
    long nUploadedBytes = 0;
    int nCounter = 0;

    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
        if (mIsCanceled){
            finalFileInputStream.close();
            nUploadedBytes = 0;
        } else {
            switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                case INITIATION_STARTED:
                    Log.i("sdm", "iniation_started");
                    break;
                case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                    Log.i("sdm", "iniation_complete");
                    break;
                case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                    Log.i("sdm", "progress : " + uploader.getNumBytesUploaded() + "/" + 
                        uploader.getMediaContent().getLength()  + String.format("(%.1f%%)", 
                        uploader.getProgress() * 100));

                    break;
                case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                    Log.i("sdm", "complete");
                    break;
                case NOT_STARTED:
                    Log.i("sdm", "not_started");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);
Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
```

And the log is:

```
iniation_started
iniation_complete
progress : 1572864/215562689(0.7%)
progress : 3145728/215562689(1.5%)
progress : 4718592/215562689(2.2%)
progress : 6291456/215562689(2.9%)
progress : 7864320/215562689(3.6%)
progress : 9437184/215562689(4.4%)
progress : 11010048/215562689(5.1%)
progress : 12582912/215562689(5.8%)
progress : 14155776/215562689(6.6%)
progress : 15728640/215562689(7.3%)
progress : 17301504/215562689(8.0%)
progress : 18874368/215562689(8.8%)
progress : 20447232/215562689(9.5%)
progress : 22020096/215562689(10.2%)
progress : 23592960/215562689(10.9%)
progress : 25165824/215562689(11.7%)
progress : 26738688/215562689(12.4%)
progress : 28311552/215562689(13.1%)
progress : 29884416/215562689(13.9%)
progress : 31457280/215562689(14.6%)
progress : 33030144/215562689(15.3%)
progress : 34603008/215562689(16.1%)
progress : 36175872/215562689(16.8%)
progress : 37748736/215562689(17.5%)
progress : 39321600/215562689(18.2%)
progress : 40894464/215562689(19.0%)
progress : 42467328/215562689(19.7%)
progress : 44040192/215562689(20.4%)
progress : 45613056/215562689(21.2%)
progress : 47185920/215562689(21.9%)
progress : 48758784/215562689(22.6%)
progress : 50331648/215562689(23.3%)
progress : 51904512/215562689(24.1%)
progress : 53477376/215562689(24.8%)
progress : 55050240/215562689(25.5%)
progress : 56623104/215562689(26.3%)
progress : 58195968/215562689(27.0%)
progress : 59768832/215562689(27.7%)
progress : 61341696/215562689(28.5%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
progress : 62914560/215562689(29.2%)
```

I don't understan why it stops in the middle. Is it a bug? Or is there anything I missed?